Conversion Factor Weighted or Dv01 Weighted Treasury Futures Hedge
When trading the US Treasury Basis, why is a conversion factor weighted number of futures to your bonds the convention over DV01 weighted number of futures? why does one prefer the conversion factor weighting?

What did you want to trade cash vs futures for ?

It is the same thing because by definition the DV01 of the futures is = DV01-of-CTD / CF

You can trade basis which is not ctd fyi

Good point. In that case definitely you should look at the DV01's.
